# How to redirect logged out users from wpforms to login page?

Tags: wordpress

I am making a website in WordPress in which I have used WPForms plugin to make some forms and Ultimate Member plugin for login and registration. I want that only logged in users can fill the form and logged out users are redirected to login page. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I will redirect not logged-in users to login page if they accessing private pages contain your form. Put below code to your theme's functions.php file:

```
if( is_page('submit') || is_post('private-post-here') ) {
    if( is_user_logged_in() === false){
        global $wp;
        wp_redirect( wp_login_url( home_url( $wp->request ) ) );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Above script do two things:

1. Check if current page is have "submit" slug or current post is have slug "private-post-here". If they not logged in, return them to login page.
2. After their successful login, redirect them to previous page.

Answer (score 0):

```
add this to your functions.php or use a plugin like wpcode and add this snippet, dont forget to change the login url below.

add_filter( 'login_url', function( $login_url, $redirect, $force_reauth ){
     // Change here your login page url
     $login_url = 'https://aqrecommends.com/login/';
     if ( ! empty( $redirect ) ) {
          $login_url = add_query_arg( 'redirect_to', urlencode( $redirect ), $login_url );
     }
     if ( $force_reauth ) {
          $login_url = add_query_arg( 'reauth', '1', $login_url );
     }
     return $login_url;
}, 10, 3);
```